# Logging objects in monolog

Tags: php, json, logging, monolog

I am using https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog for logging, I wish to include simple objects in the log entries.

I can typecast the object to an array and monolog will save it, however, I want to see it an object.

An alternative is as follows, but expect there is a much better way to do so.

How can a simple object be logged in monolog?

```
$log = new \RestApp\MyLogger(new \Monolog\Logger('server'));
$file=$c['logger']['server'];
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($file, \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($file, \Monolog\Logger::ERROR));
$log->debug('message',$simpleObject);

class MyLogger
{
    private $logger;
    public function __construct($logger)
    {
        $this->logger=$logger;
    }
    public function debug($msg, $extra=[]){
        echo($msg.': '.json_encode($extra).PHP_EOL);
        return $extra?$this->logger->debug($msg, $this->o2json($extra)):$this->logger->debug($msg);
    }
    public function error($msg, $extra=[]){
        echo($msg.': '.json_encode($extra).PHP_EOL);
        return $extra?$this->logger->error($msg, $this->o2json($extra)):$this->logger->error($msg);
    }
    public function warning($msg, $extra=[]){
        echo($msg.': '.json_encode($extra).PHP_EOL);
        return $extra?$this->logger->warning($msg, $this->o2json($extra)):$this->logger->warning($msg);
    }
    public function pushHandler($handler){
        return $this->logger->pushHandler($handler);
    }
    private function o2json($v)
    {
        if($v && !is_array($v)) {
            if(is_object($v)) $v=json_encode($v);
            $v=['prop'=>$v];
        }
        return $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "want to see it as an object"? The closest I can think of to this would be to json_encode the entire object and save it as a string

Comment: @Dale  Yes, I wish to view it as the JSON representation of an object.  Monolog complains if the second argument is anything but an array.  I "could" append the JSON to the first argument string, but this isn't very clean.  Thus I created `MyLogger`, however, don't think this is the "right" way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In Monolog it's easy to customize the format of the logs written into files, sockets, mails, databases and other handlers; by the use of "Formatters".

A Formatter is attached to a Handler, and as a general convention, most of the handlers use the `$record->formatted` property in the log record to store its formatted value.

You can choose between predefined formatters (normalizer, one line, json, ...) or write your own.

```
<?php

// the default date format is "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"
$dateFormat = "Y n j, g:i a";

// the default output format is "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n"
// we now change the default output format according to our needs.
$output = "%datetime% > %level_name% > %message% %context% %extra%\n";

// finally, create a formatter
$formatter = new LineFormatter($output, $dateFormat);

// Create a handler
$stream = new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log', Level::Debug);
$stream->setFormatter($formatter);

// bind it to a logger object
$securityLogger = new Logger('security');
$securityLogger->pushHandler($stream);
```

You may also reuse the same formatter between multiple handlers and share those handlers between multiple loggers.